# Migrating ascx to cshtml in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

There is a Menu.ascx file in my project. The Master view uses Html.RenderAction() to call a controller method that has the name Menu(). This works just fine in the old pages. I'm slowly migrating pages to razor and MVC 5. I've created a Layout view and I want to rework Menu.ascx to be more modern for the pages I'm converting. So I created a Menu.cshtml in the project. In my Layout I use the same Html.RenderAction() and it does call this. However it doesn't seem to be outputting using my Menu.cshtml.

Is there any way I can do this without screwing up the original Menu.ascx file because this would be really slick to use the same controller method for both versions of MVC views. I would have thought that because my MVC 5 layout is how Html.RenderAction() was called, that it would know to get the Menu.cshtml view when it returns View() at the end of it, but it doesn't seem to be doing that.

I could add a parameter and do some branching probably to specifically specify Menu.cshtml but then I would be editing the original controller method and I'm curious if there is a way to do this without editing it.

```
public ViewResult Menu(CurrentUser user, string vendorId)
{
   return View(myModelHere);
}
```

[UPDATE]
OK, so when I try to specify Menu.cshtml it errors out saying it can't find it and then it lists what it tried. It lists Menu.cshtml.ascx and Menu.cshtml.cshtml. So I remove the .cshtml in the controller and then it doesn't error but it's not getting the Menu.cshtml file it's getting the Menu.ascx file. So it's like the order in which it's looking for the view file ascx is first and once it finds it, it uses it. Hmmm not sure what to do here to get it to use Menu.cshtml.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had to specify the full path with extension to make this work, which means I needed to pass another parameter to the controller to know what RenderAction() I was coming from. That part I don't like.